# subclass uiwindow wont rotate to horizontal orientation

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I tried to subclass UIWindow to cover the statusBar to show something.But this custom window wont rotate when my app's orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft or right.How can I fix it?

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 20)]) {
    self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    label.text = @"testing";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:label];
    NSLog(@"label %@", label);
    [label release];

    [self makeKeyAndVisible];
  }

  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think UIWindows themselves actually rotate, rather the UIViewController you add to the window is the one that handles rotation.

Comment: So if I want to cover the status bar when the app rotate to the landscape orientation, what else can I do? I've tried to modify the transform of the window, but it wont work as I expect, the result was weird.